# How to fix import of timestamp field in hive?

Tags: datetime, import, hive

I have a file in HDFs that I imported to Hive in the following way:

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_abc_test
(
Receive_Time String,
....,
....,
....,
Row format delimited 
Fields terminated by ' '
LOCATION '/path/path/path/'
TBLPROPERTIES ( "Skip. Header. Line. count " =  "1 ");

At the time of importing a field `Date_time` in Hive, I detect the field separately because between the date and time there is a space. What can I do? Create one more column for the time or in the same field between the date and time put a  "-"

This is the field of timestamp

```
|Date_time |
|12/03/2019 0:00|
```

And hive import this

```
Date_time | id | action | 
12/03/2019 | 0:00 | 123abc | Denied
```

Comment: you should add how you are importing the data ..

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the question.